# 'url' is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Не могу понять что я сделал не так, мой код:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropsType from 'prop-types';

class Counter extends React.Component {
  propsType = {
    counter: PropsType.number,
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    state = {
      secondCounter: 0,
    }
  }

  handler = () => {
    const { counter } = this.props;
    const { secondCounter } = this.state;
    this.setState({secoundCounter: secondCounter + counter})
  }

  render() {
    const { counter } = this.props;
    const { secondCounter } = this.state;
    return(
      <>
        <div>First {counter}</div>
        <div>Second {secondCounter}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handler}>Count</button>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Я не могу понять, почему eslint постоянно подсвечивает "counter" is missing in props validation.
Определить propsType я пытался и таким образом Counter.propsType = {...} после компонента, но ничего не меняется. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не совсем правильно настроена проверка Props

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Counter extends React.Component {
static propTypes = {
    counter: PropTypes.number
};
...
```

так же в конструкторе следует писать `this.state = ...`